# Error:Qtcore module not found from while importing bbpy package

Tags: python, qt, import, pyside, blackberry-10

I am trying to get an example application running with blackberry-py. I adhered to the instructions at link: http://hg.microcode.ca/blackberry-py/wiki/Home , however when trying the 
"import bbpy" statement I received the following error: import Error: No module named Qtcore.

Print screen of Trace : https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4sfo.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of `PySide` does not have a module `QtCore`. Also note that it's trying to import `Qt` from there, not `qt` so it makes sense that `import qt` will give an error.

Are you sure you installed compatible versions of `PySide` and `bbpy`? Check the versions and lookup if they're indeed compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I downloaded a pre-built version of PySide that is supposed to be compatible, as it was provided with bbpy. I suppose building PySide myself is the next approach..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out those packages are not for PC but for playbook. Solution is to download PyQt or QT
Thanks to @peter9477 and timeless for the help on #bbx-python on freenode.net. 
If you're interested in the BBPy project check it out here : http://blackberry-py.microcode.ca/ and here: http://hg.microcode.ca/blackberry-py/wiki/Home .